# using alias parameters in window command prompt

Tags: cmd, dos, alias, command-prompt

Source:http://jpsoft.com/help/index.htm?alias.htm

> Aliases can use command line
>   parameters or parameters like those in
>   batch files. The command line
>   parameters are numbered from %0 to
>   %511. (%0 contains the alias name.)
>
> > > For example, the following alias will
> > >       change directories, perform a command,
> > >       and return to the original directory:
>
> alias in `pushd %1 & %2$ & popd`

when i run the above, my command prompt gives error saying

%1               *** Unable to read value of alias ***
'%2' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'popd`' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

if you use double quote instead,  alias in "pushd %1 & dir & popd"
it doesn't interprets the %1 when you execute the alias

C:\abc\def>alias
Dumping all defined aliases for CMD.EXE.
    in              =pushd %1 & dir & popd

alias def wont work

---------EDIT------------
let me try some sample output with a simple echo alias

D:\abc\def>alias /?

Usage: ALIAS [-v] [-p programName] [-f filespec] [ ]

```
         [-v] means verbose output.

         [-d] means delete aliases.

         [-p programName] specifies which image file name these alias

                          definitions are for.  Default is CMD.EXE

         [-f filespec] specifies a file which contains the alises.
```

C:\Office\dev15>alias out 'echo %1'

%1'              *** Unable to read value of alias ***

> C:\Office\dev15>alias out backtick echo %1 backtick

%1`              *** Unable to read value of alias ***

C:\Office\dev15>alias out "echo %1"

C:\Office\dev15>alias

Dumping all defined aliases for CMD.EXE.

```
out             =echo %1
```

C:\Office\dev15>out abc

%1

C:\Office\dev15>alias out echo %1

%1               *** Unable to read value of alias ***

C:\Office\dev15>out abc

ECHO is on.

Problem is,
both single quote and back tick produces error,
while double quote wont treat %1 as variable parameter
also tried with none of the quotes.
still wouldnot work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, try this (use copy and paste):

```
   alias dtxt = `pushd %1 & dir %2$ & popd`
```

This sets the alias '**dtxt**' to the following commands:

```
   pushd %1
   dir %2
   popd
```

**Pay particular attention to the inverted single quotes (`) around the alias definition. This is found on the top-left key on the ISO (UK) and ANSI (US) keyboards.**

You will need to supply two parameters, **%1** and **%2** when executing **dtxt** - a target pathname, and a parameter for the DIR command as in the following examples:

```
   dtxt c:\temp *.txt
```

In a nutshell, **PUSHD** pushes the current working directory name onto a LIFO stack and changes directory to *c:\temp.*

The **DIR** command then executes with **%2** as it's parameter - in this case **'*.txt**'.

Finally, **POPD** restores the previous working directory by popping it off the stack.

FYI, this is equivalent to the following standard DOS command:

```
   dir c:\temp\*.txt
```

The following command in standard DOS will also work fine:

```
   pushd & dir *.txt & popd
```

But obviously, '**dtxt**' is shorter and saves keystrokes!

Comment: Here is my output after i copy and pasted the command

D:\>alias dtxt = `pushd %1 & dir %2$ & popd`
 Volume in drive D is New Volume
 Volume Serial Number is 
 Directory of D:\
File Not Found
'popd`' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: freshWoWer, what operating system are you running this on? Also, are you using 'Take Command'? - If so, what version?